Trying to Cloak my domain only to specific country
im trying to display my domain to specific country with IP checking which if open by TH(Thai) it will show my domain example.com  but if not, it will show another page, im currently on Thai, which to check if it works, i use SG(Singapore) VPN to see if it works or not,
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (!is_bot($user_agent, $bots)) {
    $access_key = '6adf16bff8db66'; // Replace with your ipinfo.io access key
    $ch = curl_init('http://ipinfo.io/' . $ip . '?token=' . $access_key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $ip_details = json_decode($json, true);

    if ($ip_details['country'] == 'TH') {
        header('Location: https://example.com/');
        exit;
    }
}

with the codes above it keeps showing the other domain if TH is set as the designated country, but if i swap it to SG, it shows the example.com to all even if i use my TH IP, im confused
please help

What are the responses from the api for the different IP addresses.  This may show if there is an issue with the api identifying the country.

Have you checked the value of $ip_details['country']? Are you sure you are visiting the url that runs this code? Also if redirection works, then visitors can skip this check and directly visit https://example.com/.

im confused...ok, so then what debugging have you done, to get clarity? Have you verified that $ip contains the IP you were expecting to receive from the client-side in each test case? Have you checked what the IPInfo service returned into $ip_details['country'] in each test case? ...

... Maybe the IP sent isn't what you expected, or maybe the IPInfo service mis-identified the country it belongs to - it's far from an exact science and there is no magic - if your test IP isn't in its database, it won't know the answer. Or its data could just be wrong. But we don't know where we're even starting from here, because you've provided no concrete test or debugging data for anyone to work with. Please [edit] your question to provide clear info, so we can help you better. This is probably an issue with the data being used, rather than the code you've written.
